# An appoarch to proving functions are withen the class $C^{\infty}$ through function compostion?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Regarding $C^{\infty}$ functions, in the text "An Introduction to Differential Geometry Through Computation". An easier way to construct and define $C^{\infty}$ functions is given in $(1)$. The specifics of my question are essentially can Function Composition be used as a key step to prove a given function is within the class $C^{\infty}$. 
  Let $ m ,\, n, \, k \in Z^{+}$ , and let $\Psi\, : \mathbb{R^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{m}}   , \, \Phi : \mathbb{R^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{l}}$. The composition of the two functions $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ is the function $\Psi \circ \,  \Phi: \mathbb{R^{n}}: \mathbb{R^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{l}}$. Is initially defined in $(1.2)$

$$(1.2)$$
$$( \Psi \circ \Phi)(x)= \Psi(\Phi(x))$$

Initially noting  and considering $(1.2)$ in further detail putting in the context of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ could it be possible to use Function Compostion as a technique to assit proving functions withen the class $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: I would suspect this not to be the case in general. The class $C^{\infty}$ is all infinitely differentiable functions, and I don't think compositions can always force a function to be infinitely differentiable (without using the obvious trivial maps).

Comment: Interesting I initially asked because I did see an inductive approach to proving functions are within the class $C^{\infty}$ and initially wondered of composition of functions could be helpful.

Comment: The inductive step would be showing that if it's a member of $C^{n}$, then it's a member of $C^{n+1}$ --- I'm not sure how a composition approach would help.

Comment: The composition of $C^{\infty}$ functions is $C^{\infty}$ (chain rule $+$ induction). Are you thinking in something beyond this?